# Plugin for NetBeans for creating class template

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I am looking for plugin for NetBeans PHP (or it can be some external tool) that would do something like that:

- When run it asks for a class name and the names of private attributes (and their types) of this class
- Then it generates this class with:

  - all listed attributes with types in vdoc format,
  - constructor that takes all the attributes as parameters and initialize class attributes with those values,
  - default getters and setters.

I know it's not difficult to write such tool, but maybe it already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans has some built-in functionality similar to this already. In any PHP project, create a new PHP Class (right click a folder in the project, New -> PHP Class). Enter your [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), such as:

```
class user
{
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $email;
    private $firstname;

    | <-- position the cursor here and press Alt+Insert
}
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> will bring up a menu that allows you to generate a constructor, getters, and setters to assign values to your properties.

If you want to do more, you can look at this [Netbeans article on code generation](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-generator.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's not such plugin for NetBEans (AFAIK), but it's not the job for it anyway. Such classes can be created automatically from YAML/XML/database schema meta data. ORMs usually have tools for that, but creating your own should not be difficult either.